# Как изменить значения во всех Edittext из ListView при изменении одного?

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-edittext

**activity_convert.xml**

```
androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ConvertActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        style="@style/Toolbar"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_currency_conv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/calculator"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**convert_item.xml**

Здесь три элемента:

1. Символьный код валюты
2. Текущее значение валюты относительно рубля
3. Поле для ввода

   ```
   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/vcCharCode"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
       android:textSize="20sp">
   </TextView>

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/vcValue"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </TextView>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/vInput"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
       android:ems="10"
       android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
   ```

Код адаптера **ConvertAdapter**

```
public class ConvertAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Valute> {

String TAG = "ConvertAdapter";
private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<Valute> valute;

   public ConvertAdapter(Activity context, int convert_item, ArrayList<Valute> valute) {

       super(context, R.layout.convert_item, valute);
       this.context = context;
       this.valute = valute;
   }

   public class ViewHolder

   {
       TextView vCharCode;
       TextView vValue;
       EditText vInput;
   }

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      ConvertAdapter.ViewHolder holder = null;

       if(convertView == null)
       {
          LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.convert_item, parent,false);

          holder = new ConvertAdapter.ViewHolder();

          holder.vCharCode = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vcCharCode);
          holder.vValue = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vcValue);
          holder.vInput = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vInput);

          convertView.setTag(holder);
      }

      else
      {
        holder = (ConvertAdapter.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
      }

      holder.vCharCode.setText(valute.get(position).getCharCode());
      holder.vValue.setText(valute.get(position).getValue().toString());
      final String valuePosition = valute.get(position).getValue().toString();
      holder.vInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
          public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: " + valuePosition);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "afterTextChanged: ");
        }

      });

    return convertView; 
  }
}
```

Вся информация о валютах храниться в ArrrayList.
Задача в следующем: при изменении значения в одном editText, автоматически изменять значениях во всех editText, опираясь на значение vValue элемента ListView.

Например: Ввожу 5 долларов и в поля других валют подсчитываются их значения относительно доллара.

В данном куске кода:

```
    final String valuePosition = valute.get(position).getValue().toString();
    holder.vInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence,int i,int i1,int i2){
                Log.d(TAG,"onTextChanged: "+valuePosition);
        }
    }
```

Вытаскивается значение валюты соответствующего поля.
Как мне вытаскивать все vValue и заносить подсчитанное в их поля?

**ConvertActivity**

```
public class ConvertActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ListView listValute;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_convert);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ArrayList<Valute> valuteArrayList = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelableArrayList("valute");

    listValute = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_currency_conv);
    ConvertAdapter converAdapter = new ConvertAdapter(ConvertActivity.this, R.layout.convert_item, valuteArrayList);
    listValute.setAdapter(converAdapter);
}
}
```

Comment: Возможно ли было использовать 
`listValue.getChildAt(int)`? Ведь известно количество элементов и их порядок. Например, `((EditText) listValue.getChildAt(0).findViewById(R.id.vInput)).setText(String);`

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов не понимаю как использовать ваше предложение.
Можете пояснить подробнее?